# Rails. Dropdown1 enables Drobdown2 selection using Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two DropDowns (say DropDown1 and DropDown2) in my `_form.html.erb`.
Here is the `_form.html.erb`'s code (Where I need assistance);

```
  <div class="input-group">
    <%= f.label :flight_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :flight_id, Flight.all, :id, :airline %>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <%= f.label :seat_no %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :seat_no %>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <%= f.label :hotel_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :hotel_id, Hotel.all, :id, :hotel_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <%= f.label :room_no %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :room_no %>
 </div>
```

Here I want to convert the `seat_no` and `room_no` as dependent `Drop down` lists, dependent on `Flight` and `Hotel` respectively.
When I select `Flight` Seats against that `Flight` should become available in the `Seat` drop down list, and same logic for the `Room` drop down list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby will be not enough for this. You need to use javascript to achieve what you want. Let's go with seats. If you expect seats to be loaded depending on flight, you should first setup a controller action which will accept fligh_id and return array of seats in JSON format. I would put this controller into namespace and place it in `app/controllers/ajax/seats_controller.rb`:

```
class Ajax::SeatsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @seats = Seat.where(fligh_id: params[:flight_id])
    render json: @seats
  end
end
```

in `routes.rb`:

```
namespace :ajax do
  resources :seats_controller, only: :index
end
```

Then rewrite seats input like:

```
<div class="input-group" style="display: none">
  <%= f.label :seat_no %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :seat_no %>
</div>
```

in `app/assets/javascripts/[your_controller].js`:

```
$('#[your_flight_dropdown_html_id]').onchange(function() {
  $.getJSON('/ajax/seats', { flight_id: $('#[your_flight_dropdown_html_id]').val(), function(data) {
    // destroy all existing seat options
    // loop through data and fill in new seat options
    // Make seats dropdown visible
  }
});
```

It's short description how would I go with your task. You can do the same for another pair of dropdown. Maybe there are some bugs in my code (haven't tested it), but at least you will have common understanding how to move forward.

Write a comment in case of any help needed

Comment: Does this helped you?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the help dude..!

Comment: @SattarJamali you are welcome. It would be great if you mark my question as a valid answer (with a green tick to the left) for future visitors. Thanks in advance

Comment: Dear @AntonTkachov, I have marked when I was done, but due to reputations, my marking as a valid answer is not being showed. :(